# Single print page bounds?

Tags: c#, winforms, wysiwyg

I will be printing **one** page. I want to show the user what he is about to print and how does it fit on the paper. It's that **WYSIWYG** thing. No preview just draw borders live when editing the document.

When the PrintPage event is fired, I have `e.PageBounds = {X=0,Y=0,Width=827,Height=1169}` *ISO 216, A4*. But it's too late.

---

**Question:** How do I get those bounds **before** I print ?
I will be using *ISO 216, A3, A4*.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the page bounds depend on the printer chosen.  So you can't know what they are until you choose a printer to print on.  You may be able to use the classes in the System.Printing namespace to get the capabilities of the printer upon which you wish to print.

Comment: e.PageBounds is simply PageSettings.Bounds.  Which is something you determine *before* you print so no problem.  Use the PageSetupDialog class to let the user pick another page or alter the margins.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default page bounds from a printer driver with `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings`, but this can be different from the `PrintPageEventArgs` when the document is actually printed; the user could change the printer or margins from the print dialog.

Even if you do not show a print dialog and only print to the default printer, WYSIWYG is very difficult as the printer could perform font substitution.